# Minimum length of source string for cipher

Tags: ruby, encryption

Is there a minimum length for the source string for cipher? I am trying to create unique session ids, and am doing the following:

```
cipherer = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc").encrypt

cipherer.update(Time.now.to_f.*(1000).to_i.to_s(36))
```

but it returns an empty string. I changed the multiplication factor `1000` to larger ones like `100000000000000`, and then it sometimes returns an empty string and sometimes a long string. I suppose this is because strings shorter than some length are mapped to empty strings by the cipher. Is this understanding correct? If so, what is the minimum length, and how can I make it so that it never returns an empty string? I don't need to decipher it, so there is no worry about whether the rounding error or hardware dependency will make it impossible to decipher.

Comment: Maybe a UUID generator gem would work better?

Comment: I am not a crypto expert but i have never heard of a cipher that just throws away input because it's too short. All ciphers i know use some sort of [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) in order to allow for variable-length strings.

Comment: I agree a UUID generator would probably be a better fit, e.g. `require 'securerandom'; SecureRandom.uuid` gives you a UUID v4 according to  RFC 4122, something like `"92a1517b-9c8b-4fc8-b31e-0920fcc6323b"`

Comment: Oh and another thing: The only thing i really learned in crypto class was “never bake your own [cipher/hash/whatever crypto stuff]” ;-)

Comment: I don't want to use random strings because they are not unique (even though the probability to crash is low). On the other hand, I can control not to generate more than one session id per millisecond, which will ensure that strings generated from them will be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES Block Size is 128 Bit = 16 Bytes which is 16 characters. This means 16 Bytes go in and 16 Bytes go out.

You are using the streaming mode by calling `OpenSSL::Cipher#update`. This means that the input to the `update` method is appended to the input for the cipher until a minimum of 16 Bytes is reached. Only then, an encryption can be performed and only then the method will return an actual value.

This means, that a call to `update` will only produce an output every second time if you feed it with an 8 Bytes value which is what you do:

```
cipherer = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc").encrypt
#=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007fb67426e558>
cipherer.update('X'*8)
#=> ""
cipherer.update('X'*8)
#=> "\xA0+\xD8Y\xA5\xBC68\x972\x86!\xC7\xE5\xA2\xDE"
cipherer.update('X'*8)
#=> ""
cipherer.update('X'*8)
#=> "\xFB\xB1I\xE2\x01\xB8Z\x10\xDC\x96m?\xC3\x00\x19+"
```

On the other hand, two blocks will be encrypted at once if you provide a 32 Byte value, e.g.

```
cipherer = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc").encrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007fb6741579f8>
cipherer.update('X'*32)
#=> "\xA0+\xD8Y\xA5\xBC68\x972\x86!\xC7\xE5\xA2\xDE\xFB\xB1I\xE2\x01\xB8Z\x10\xDC\x96m?\xC3\x00\x19+"
cipherer.update('X'*32)
#=> "\xB2!\xBA>M\x13t\xEBv^\xCE\xAE\x18\x9A\xE3S\xD96\x95\x89\xC1\xB4\xAA\xDD\xD3\xDCp\e<\x90\xA79"
cipherer.update('X'*32)
#=> "\x95\xA3-\xB9\x93D\x1D\xC0\xB3mh\xE3\xB5N\x9C\x8C\xEA\xF3\x80\xD3\xBDU\xCB'\xC0E\xDA\x02\xA8L\a\xB3"
```

The direct solution to your problem is to use a string as input that is guaranteed to be 16 Bytes long.

I strongly encourage you to use the UUID implementation that comes with ruby, though. There are so many things to think about when implementing crypto stuff. You're always better off sticking to the standards and using well-known, widely-used and battle-tested implementations. That said, here's how to get a UUID:

```
require 'securerandom'

SecureRandom.uuid
#=> "c5059a24-25fc-4617-aaf7-280df52cd8d3"
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my question. As for generating uuid, I found a gem called uuidtools, which has a method `UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create` that uses the timestamp, which fulfills my requirement that it be unique.

Comment: Well a uuid v4 consists of 32 significant hexadecimal chars so there are 16**32 = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 possible uuids. so it is veeeeeeeeeeeery unlikely that you get the same uuid twice :)

Comment: Actually `UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create` also has 32 significant hex chars, so the chance to pick the same uuid twice is exactly the same

Comment: But it is ensured that it is unique. It even uses `lock` to avoid two uuids being generated in the same millisecond. When all the possibilities are used up, that is when the maximum expressible time has been reached, which will happen in the long future, when I will probably not be alive.

Comment: Yes, you will never get the same UUID on the same machine. But it may still happen that two machines generate a UUID in the same microsecond and generate the same UUID. In this case, a random UUID would probably be safer. Whatever, i think both are valid solutions and insist on the fact that the probability is so small that it will not matter while you're alive.

Comment: Non-random UUIDs used directly as session keys are not cryptographically secure. A requirement for guaranteed uniqueness necessarily reduces the entropy. If you use non-random UUID for a session key, you will *also* want to use additional crypto on it, such that it can't be guessed. If you want to keep generation simple, and rely on un-guessable session keys (as opposed to a signature based scheme), then I'd back other assertions here to use Ruby's SecureRandom based v4 UUIDs, and not `timestamp_create`, because it is not secure

Comment: Sorry, one last minute thought - UUID-based sessions always work off server-side storage. And they need to be read on every access. So checking whether a randomly-generated new session already exists is inexpensive (or at least a price you expect to pay on every request already) and prevents worries you have with random UUIDs.